# unable to include stylesheet for page template in child theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I have created a child theme and have created a page-splash.php in the child theme and have also created a page-splash.css for this page, but somehow I am unable to load the page-splash.css for the page-splash.php file.

This is my code in the functions.php ( in the child theme folder)

```
 <?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

function splash_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'page-splash', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/page-spash.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'splash_enqueue_style' );


?>
```

I'd really appreciate your help on this.
What am I doing wrong??
I am working in localhost and will transfer these files to a working domain after things are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, starting with the simplest -- You've got a typo in your page-splash.css file path. You've got it typed as page-spash.css

Additionally, there's probably no need to call two separate functions for this. You could enqueue both of those styles in one call like so:

```
function splash_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    if(is_page_template('page-splash.php'){
      //Path to your template.. if it's in a dir, include it before the file
      wp_enqueue_style( 'page-splash', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/page-splash.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'splash_enqueue_style' );
```

Comment: thanks for this info, I will try this out.
By the way, I am having problems getting my page-splash.css to work as it seems to be overridden by parent themes css files.
how do I fix that??

Comment: What do you mean by "overridden"? Is the splash style being loaded in the page, but all the CSS in it is being overridden? or instead is the file not being loaded at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kept on searching for answers and I have found it. 
It seems that using wp_head() is important if you want to load all javascript
or css files and it started to work when I did that.

Comment: Oh yeah, that too